Inability to get tempdata from action to another action in ASP.NET Core 6
I use TempData in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. In action method offer2, I set value to TempData and access it in view offer2.
But when I use RedirectToAction, in action offer3, The TempData['Name'] TempData does not exist.
public IActionResult Offer2()
{
    TempData["Name"] = "Pranaya";
    TempData["Age"] = 30;

    TempData.Keep("Name");
    TempData.Keep("Age"); 

    return RedirectToAction("Offer3");  
} 

public IActionResult Offer3()
{ 
    if (TempData.Peek("Name") != null)
    {
        var name = TempData["Name"].ToString();   
        ViewBag.Name = name;
    }

    return View();
}

My question is that despite writing command TempData.Keep("Name") I can't retrieve TempData["Name"] in offer3
in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>(); // Add in 'Startup.cs' file 'ConfigureServices' method //zare_nk_0202_added

builder.Services.AddSession();  


app.UseSession();


I my test your code is working without a problem. Try to put breakpoint on the TempData.Peek() line and check what items the TempData dictionary contains.   Try to clean up the browser cached data, restart the Visual Studio. If this doesn't help try upgrade your project to .NET 8. Perhaps even this is a bug in ASP.NET Core like this one -  TempData never cleared - survives browser and process restarts.

Do any special settings need to be made in program.cs?

Hi @reza, it seems erverything is correct. Did you do any other operation for the TempData, did you just call the offer2 action and then recirect to offer3? You cannot get into the if clause in offer3 action, right? And it is better for you to share the whole Program.cs file.
